# vb.net USB flash drive IO error device not ready

Tags: vb.net, usb-drive, ioerror

I have an app that searches for drives that begin with "CVD". The user will have multiple flash drives that I pull data from when inserted in to PC. This works perfectly on my development PC, but when the user runs it on their PC they receive an IO error "device not ready". The user PC can physically recognizes the inserted USB flash drive and I can see the files using windows file explorer.

My development PC is Win10 and the users are using Win7. Any thoughts on how I can force the USB flash drive to "ready" state?

```
 Private Sub FindDrives()

    Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim d As DriveInfo

    For Each d In allDrives
        If d.VolumeLabel.StartsWith("CVD") Then
            DrivePath = d.Name
            CVDname = d.VolumeLabel
            CVDTextBox.Text = CVDname
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If DrivePath = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No drive starting with 'CVD' was found." & vbCr & "Application will now close.")
        Application.Exit()
        End
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know it is the USB that is not ready?  Since it is a different system it could be some other drive causing the problem

Comment: I know it’s the USB flash drive because it’s discovered, filtered, and assigned to the correct drive path. When I search the files on the discovered flash drive in another routine, it throws the “not ready” error.